# Zend Form Decorator - adding options to tag of an input Label

Tags: zend-form, decorator

I'm trying to achieve the following html output using Zend_Form Decorator:

```
<tr>
  <td id="from-label" **class="labelcell"**><label for="from" class="required">From</label></td> 
  <td><input type="text" name="from" id="from" value="" class="text"></td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to add class attribute and for example inline style attribute on the enclosing tag of the Label. In the above example I want to add `class="labelcell`"

The decorator statements are as follows:

```
    $from = $this->createElement('text', 'from', array(
                            'validators'=> array(array('regex', false, '/^[0-9]+/i')),
                            'required'=> true,
                            'label'=> 'From'
                        )
                    );
        $from->setAttrib('class', 'text');
        $from->setDecorators(
                array(
                'ViewHelper',
                'Description',
                'Errors',
                array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),
                array('Label', array('tag' => 'td')),
                array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr'))
                ));
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want without extending the Zend_Form_Decorator_Label to pass additional option to the enclosing tag?

Answer (score 2):

```
$from->setDecorators(array(
'ViewHelper',
'Description',
'Errors',
array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array(
    'tag' => 'td'
)),
array('Label', array(
    'tag'   => 'td',
    'class' => 'labelcell'
    'tagClass' => 'YourClassNameHere' <- THIS IS WHAT WILL ADD TO LABEL WRAPPER

)),
array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array(
    'tag' => 'tr'
)),
```

));

Answer (score 1):

There is an option *class*. You should be able to define it in your config array, too. Try this:

```
$from->setDecorators(array(
    'ViewHelper',
    'Description',
    'Errors',
    array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array(
        'tag' => 'td'
    )),
    array('Label', array(
        'tag'   => 'td',
        'class' => 'labelcell'
    )),
    array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array(
        'tag' => 'tr'
    )),
));
```